# Self realization of a simple mistake rendering my question "too localized" 

Tags: discussion, too-localized

I posted a question on Stack Overflow, giving some details about a situation I did not understand. A couple of people offered help and suggestions ; however, after a while I realized my problem came from a very stupid mistake of mine (in a part of the code I had not really posted about as I thought it was irelevant).

So, on the bright side, hurray for SO and its community for having acted as my rubber duck.

However, what is the best way to deal with this kind of situation? Should I simply edit the question's content? It's title? Should I 'delete' it (and in this case, what happens to the people who have so generously helped?) How can I 'reward' the other posters for giving some time, when the problem was really sitting between chair and keyboard?

Answer (score 6):

If you feel that your post genuinely would **not benefit** any future visitors then you should flag your post for moderator attention and **request that the post be deleted**.  You can't simply delete your own post because it already has answers.

If you feel that the code you left out (and the  mistake that it contained) *could* **help someone in the future** then you can just **add the relevant information to the existing post and vote on the answers** that were given (that will "reward" the helpful users that tried to help).

In most cases of "silly mistakes" the best option is to remove that post (or close it as "too localized").  It is sad that any points rewarded to users from votes will be removed but that's life!  It happens!

What is important is that you became aware of this issue and are **keen to rectify it**.  A comment on answers that attempted to help saying "thank you very much for your time but..." would also be appropriate if you want to alert the users that helped of the update...

Comment: OK, I closed it as 'too localised', and flagged it... Thanks.